# Como sincronizar tela cheia e minimizada c#

Tags: c#

Olá!

Como eu faço para ter uma ideia do Design do Windows Forms no Visual Studio para telas diferentes? posicionar os botões certinho e etc...

Os forms feitos em Java tem essa função automática, mas no VS eu não consegui achar ;c

Comment: Você quer dizer ver mais de uma tela, lado a lado por exemplo?

Comment: Isso, exatamente

Comment: Só clicar na aba do Visual Studio e arrastar ela pro lado e vai aparecer os ícones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, sua dúvida é ter 2 telas (ou mais) lado a lado no momento em que estiver fazendo o design das mesmas.

Bom, se for isso basta arrastar a aba do documento que estiver editando, que será o de uma das telas, em seguida aparecerá no centro da tela opções de posicionamento para as mesmas. Assim então você posicionará as telas lado a lado como desejar.